# Navigation button not visible in google map android

Tags: android, google-maps

navigation button not visible when we call the navigation intent with own credential in google map android.

This is my code that i call in my activity.

```
public void NavigatePath(){

   Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=" + Sourcelat + "," + Sourcelong + "&daddr=" + Destinationlat + "," + Destinationlong);
   Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
   mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
   startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

Please recommend me how to visible navigation button.

Answer (score 1):

i am using this, and it working perfectly:

```
 String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f", sourceLatitude, sourceLongitude, destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
            try
            {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex)
            {
                try
                {
                    Intent unrestrictedIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                    startActivity(unrestrictedIntent);
                }
                catch(ActivityNotFoundException innerEx)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please install google maps application!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```

Comment: It work for me but  i  want to get source and destination filled. not filled by own.

Comment: sorry, but i don't know how to get that.